# Kendo UI Custom "No Records" message with transalation

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a HTML Code snippets displaying a kendo grid.

```
 <kendo-grid [data]="gridHelper.gridData"
                    [pageSize]="gridHelper.pageSize"
                    [skip]="gridHelper.skip"
                    [selectable]="gridHelper.selectable"
                    [scrollable]="gridHelper.scrollable"
                    [pageable]="false"
                    (pageChange)="gridHelper.onPageChange($event)"
                    (selectionChange)="gridHelper.onSelectRow($event)"
                    (dataStateChange)="gridHelper.onDataStateChange($event)">

                    <kendo-grid-messages
                    noRecords="{{'a.b.No_Data' | translate}}">
                </kendo-grid-messages>


 <kendo-grid-column title="{{'a.b.No_Data' | translate}}">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>

              <div>{{dataItem.modified_at}}</div>
            </ng-template>
          </kendo-grid-column>
  </kendo-grid>
```

Here "NoRecords" coming from json file and printing exactly. But my issue is when I change my language from dropdown,
 the below kendo grid column "title" is getting changed but this noRecords remain same. How can I achive to  transalate?

Answer (score 2):

Kendo Grid has a template when there are no data.

Try following:

```
 <ng-template kendoGridNoRecordsTemplate>
    <span>{{'a.b.No_Data' | translate}}</span>
 </ng-template>
```